# 406: not acceptable response received using LWP::UserAgent/File::Download

Tags: perl, http-request

Edit: it seems the issue was caused by a dropped cookie.  There should have been a session id cookie as well.

For posterity, here's the original question

> When sending a request formed as this
>
> ```
> GET https://<url>?<parameters>
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
> Connection: keep-alive
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
> Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1,utf-8,UTF-8
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate, x-bzip2
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
> If-None-Match: "6eb7d55abfd0546399e3245ad3a76090"
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 libwww-perl/6.13
> Cookie: auth_token=<blah>; __cfduid=<blah>
> Cookie2: $Version="1"
> ```
>
> I receive the following response
>
> ```
> response-type: text/html
> charset=utf-8
> HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Connection: keep-alive
> Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2016 18:34:00 GMT
> Server: cloudflare-nginx
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> CF-RAY: 273a62969a9b288e-SJC
> Client-Date: Fri, 12 Feb 2016 18:34:00 GMT
> Client-Peer: <IP4>:443
> Client-Response-Num: 10
> Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limite
> d/CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
> Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domai
> n/CN=ssl<blah>.cloudflaressl.com
> Client-SSL-Cipher: <some value>
> Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
> Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified
> Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Status: 406 Not Acceptable
> X-Runtime: 9
> ```
>
> I'm not entirely sure why the response is `406 Not Acceptable`. When
>   downloaded with firefox, the file in question in 996 KB (as reported
>   by Windows 8.1's explorer). It looks like I have a partially
>   transferred file from my perl script at 991 KB (again, windows
>   explorer size), so it got MOST of the file before throwing the `Not
>   Acceptable` response. Using the same URL pattern and request style, I
>   was able to successfully download a 36 MB file from the server with
>   this perl library and request form, so the size of the file should not
>   be magically past some max (chunk) size.  As these files are being
>   updated on approximately 15-minute intervals, I suppose it's possible
>   that a write was performed on the server, invalidating the ETag before
>   all chunks were complete on this file?
>
> I tried adding chunked to `Accept-Encoding`, but that's not for
>   *`Transfer`* encoding and it appears to have no affect on the server's behavior.  Additionally, as I've been able to download larger files
>   (same format) from the same server, that alone shouldn't be the cause
>   of my woes.  LWP is supposed to be able to handle chunked data
>   returned by a response to `GET` (as [per this](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.libwww/2001/11/msg3100.html) newsgroup post).
>
> The server in question is running `nginx` with `Rack::Lint`. The
>   particular server configuration (which I in no way control), throws
>   `500` errors on its own attempts to send `304: not modified`. This
>   caused me to write a workaround for File::Download (sub
>   [`lintWorkAround` here](https://github.com/MPagel/file-download-1/blob/master/lib/File/Download.pm)), so I'm not above putting blame on the
>   server in this instance also, if warranted. I don't believe I buggered
>   up the chunk-handling code from File::Download 0.3 (see [diff](https://github.com/MPagel/file-download-1/commit/70ecd69da6182818bde1b879b0c25ee2aba239d9)),
>   but I suppose that's also possible.  Is it possible to request a
>   particular chunk size from the server?
>
> I'm using `LWP` and `libwww` versions 6.13 in `perl` 5.18.2.
>   `File::Download` version is [my own 0.4_050601](https://github.com/MPagel/file-download-1).
>
> So, what else could the 406 error mean? Is there a way to request that
>   the server temporarily cache/version control the entire file so that I
>   can download a given ETag'd file once the transfer begins?